# Why does my Controller not pass instance variables for js.erb file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, highcharts

I am constructing a highchart for an html page supplied by instance variables from my rails controller. The problem that I am receiving is that my rails instance variables set in the controller are not being passed to my corresponding js.erb file. I have yet to determine what the cause is. Could someone help pinpoint what the problem could be? Below is the code:

Controller

```
class VulnerabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  helper ProjectsHelper
  before_action :set_project_or_fail
  before_action :set_best_project_security_set
  before_action :set_releases
  before_action :set_vulnerabilities

  def index
    @release_versions = @releases.map { |r| r.version }
  end

  private 

  def set_project_or_fail
    project_id = params[:project_id] || params[:id]
    @project = Project.by_vanity_url_or_id(project_id).take
    raise ParamRecordNotFound unless @project
  end

  def set_best_project_security_set
    @best_project_security_set = @project.best_project_security_set
  end

  def set_releases
    @releases = @best_project_security_set.releases.limit(10)
  end

  def set_vulnerabilities
    @vulnerabilities = @best_project_security_set.vulnerabilities
  end
end
```

Here is the html file:

vulnerabilities/index.html.haml

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

and here is part of the vulnerabilities.js.erb file:

```
$(function () {
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Vulnerabilities per Version',
        align: 'left',
        style: {
            color: '#336699',
            fontSize: 16
        }
    },
    legend: {
        align:  'left',
      itemWidth: 127
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: <%- @release_versions %>
    },

    ...........code.........
```

`@release_versions` returns nil everytime. I have tried

`categories: <%- @release_versions %>`
`categories: [<%- @release_versions %>]`
`categories: [<%= @release_versions %>]`
`categories: <%= @release_versions %>`

None of these variations have worked. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the name of your JS response template match the action which is rendering it? In your example you have `vulnerabilities.js.erb` but if the `index` action is being called, then the name of the response template should be `index.js.erb` no?

Comment: Thanks for the response Carlos Ramirez. The js.erb file name should not matter. I have the `vulnerabilities.js.erb` file required in `application.js` under `require tree` hence the file should be loaded in the application.

Comment: Rails controllers do not pass instance variable data to JS files unless they are specifically rendered by the controller itself. So if you are just including a `.js.erb` file in your asset pipeline then those variables will not be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To utilize a Rails controller to populate data needed for a JS template, you'll need to call the controller action from your JS (or view template) directly.

```
// in a view template or UJS call
<script>    
    // make an AJAX request to the '/vulnerabilities' URL
    $.ajax(...);
</script>

// VulnerabilitiesController#index action is called; index.js.erb template is rendered

// in vulnerabilities/index.js.erb
// here the instance variables from the controller action are defined
$('#container').highcharts({
    // ...
    xAxis: {
        categories: <%- @release_versions %>
    },
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this Carlos. You were right about the name filing conventions and of it wasn't working because I had the conventions  all wrong.

Comment: Happy I could help!